# MapInfo-XYZ Tiles

Tags: mapinfo, tiles, xyz-tiles

I can open XYZ tiles (for example [http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)) on QGIS. But is there a way to open on MapInfo ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Please give more details, for example, the MapInfo version, I think the answer would not be the same (I can for example say that is impossible in MapInfo v1 ...)

Comment: MapInfo Pro v10.5 and higher supports tile servers (XYZ Tiles) in Spherical Mercator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Create Table statement via the MapBasic window to create a Tile Server table.

Here's a statement for creating a OSM Tile Server table:

```
Create Table OSM_TileServer 
    File "OSM_TileServer" 
    Type TILESERVER 
    TileType "LevelRowColumn" 
    URL "http://someURL/{LEVEL}/{ROW}/{COL}.png" 
    AttributionText "OSM Map" Font("Arial",255,16,0,255) 
    MinLevel 0 
    MaxLevel 15 
    Height 256 
    CoordSys Earth Projection 10, 157, 7, 0 Bounds(-20037508.34,-20037508.34) (20037508.34,20037508.34)
```